# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I can compile it. However, when I input my date and time I get the error. Below is the code in question regarding this issue. error code: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'.

```
class evaluation():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.data['Date'])

    # Will receive 'actual' datetime from df, and user defined 'start' and 'stop' datetimes.
    def in_range(self, actual, start, stop):
        return start <= actual <= stop

    def evaluate(self):
        user_start = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter your start date (yyyy-mm-dd hour:min:second): "))
        user_stop = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter your end date (yyyy-mm-dd hour:min:second): "))

        # creates series of True or False selecting proper rows.
        print(self.data['Date'].dtype)
        mask = self.data['Date'].apply(self.in_range, args=(user_start, user_stop))

        # Do the groupby and sum on only those rows.
        montant_init = self.data.loc[mask].groupby("Initiateur")["Montant (centimes)"].sum()
        print(montant_init)
```

traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\vps_project\main.py", line 31, in <module>
   init_evalobj.evaluations()
 File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\vps_project\main.py", line 24, in evaluations
   self.evaluate()
 File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\vps_project\evaluation.py", line 20, in evaluate
   mask = self.data['Date'].apply(self.in_range, args=(user_start, user_stop))
 File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\vps_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4138, in apply
   mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
 File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2467, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
 File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\vps_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4123, in f
   return func(x, *args, **kwds)
 File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\vps_project\evaluation.py", line 13, in in_range
   return start <= actual <= stop
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
output:
Enter your start date (yyyy-mm-dd hour:min:second): 2021.06.06 11:00:00

Enter your end date (yyyy-mm-dd hour:min:second): 2021.06.06 12:00:00

object

+ traceback error
```

thanks

Comment: What is the output of `print(self.data['Date'])` if you put it right above `mask = self.data['Date'].apply...`?

Comment: output: 
0     09.06.2021 11:19:09
1     09.06.2021 11:19:02
2     09.06.2021 11:18:56
3     09.06.2021 11:18:53
4     09.06.2021 11:18:38
             ...         
95    08.06.2021 11:12:40
96    08.06.2021 11:12:40
97    08.06.2021 11:12:39
98    07.06.2021 11:12:25
99    07.06.2021 11:12:19

Comment: What is the output of `self.data['Date'].dtype` ?

Comment: it outputs object

Comment: Please add the output in the question (so it's formatted) and keep the last line too

Comment: "object" is the data type used for strings. Are you sure you added the changes I asked you to make in the answer and reran the code?

Comment: I edited everything to the latest edits and added output in the question too

Comment: Yes I did; as you can see in the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime(self.data['Date'])` is not modifying `self.data['Date']`, you're throwing the result away, so when you reach `in_range` one of the arguments is still a string.

Change it to `self.data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.data['Date'])`.

Comment: thank you for your answer; however I still have the error even after modifying as you told me sadly

Comment: Then please add the full error traceback to the question

Comment: Done; please check my newly edited question

Comment: It worked; when I wrote that line right above the mask. I don't know how it fixed it. do you mind explaining if you know?

Comment: I think you had some stale data left in your object instance. By writing it right before the line where it raised the error, you ensured the line was actually executed (compared to having it in the class initialization, where it is executed only when a new instance is created)

Comment: I have another question, but it's not related to this question. I was wondering if I could ask you. Of course, if you are available.

Comment: You can try, not sure I can answer that one :P But please make it a new questions, it's SO policy to keep questions and answers self-contained

Comment: thank you! here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938292/sorting-my-data-frame-by-date-d-m-y-hour-min-sec